# Does the new Raspberry Pi High Quality Camera have a global shutter or a rolling shutter?

Tags: camera

Can you tell me if the new Raspberry Pi High Quality Camera has a global shutter or a rolling shutter?

The following website says "rolling shutter", but it is not clear to me if they're talking about the "Camera Module v1", the "Camera Module v2", the "HQ Camera", or all three.

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/camera/

Thanks.

Comment: All of the RPi official cameras use a rolling shutter.

Answer (score 4):

As Dougie states page 108 of the [new camera book](https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/books/camera-guide) states

> The first thing to note about the Raspberry Pi HQ Camera and Camera Module is that they both feature a rolling shutter. So, when capturing an image, the camera reads out the pixels from the sensor one row at a time. Unlike the global shutter on a DSLR
>   camera, it also lacks a physical shutter that covers the sensor when not in use.

Also note:

> In addition, the HQ Camera or Camera Module acts more like a video camera than a
>   stills camera, as it is rarely idle. Once initialised, it is constantly streaming rows of frames down the ribbon cable to Raspberry Pi for processing.

...

> For more details on how the camera hardware works, see the picamera documentation at [magpi.cc/cameradoc](http://magpi.cc/cameradoc).